# Payment Gateway with stored monetary value support in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway, payment

I'm looking for a `Payment Gateway` that support a stored monetary value.
Like a credit point for my own web,

here's my scenario to use the `Payment Gateway`

1. User Login to my Web through their ID
2. User buy credit point (that will be used in my Web) using credit card through your system
3. If user successfully pay, the credit point will be added to the User that's logged in to my Web
4. User use the credit point with a certain amount to upload image in my Web

If possible, I want it can process payment both `Credit Card` and `PayPal` or just `Credit Card` is okay too, and my location is in Southern Asia.

Did anyone have a suggestions of a good Payment Gateway that I can use

**Edit :**
I don't want to use PayPal because the user need to Login to their PayPal account first.
The payment that I want to build is like the one in this website [123rf](http://www.123rf.com/islogin_globalv8.6b.php) `(the OnDemand one)` and preferably if the `Payment Gateway` can support `Transparent Redirect`